# Not sure how to convert this macro to use multidimensional Array instead of using sheet comparisons

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I have a `For Each` loop that does what I want it to do but it takes 22 min to process. I have converted similar loops into array comparisons to speed up the process but I have not been successful in using multi-dimensional Arrays.

I have 1 spreadsheet that needs to be updated and the 2nd spreadsheet contains all the items I need to find over several columns.

Here is the Code I am using to update the data in my spreadsheet.

```
lr_counter = inv_wb.Worksheets(6).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = inv_wb.Worksheets(6).Range("A2:A" & lr_counter)

lr_counter = vl_wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng2 = vl_wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:A" & lr_counter)

For Each cell In rng1
    For Each cellx In rng2
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) And Trim(cell.Value) = Trim(cellx.Value) Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1) = cellx.Offset(0, 1).Value
            cell.Offset(0, 2) = cellx.Offset(0, 2).Value
            cell.Offset(0, 3) = cellx.Offset(0, 3).Value
            cell.Offset(0, 6) = cellx.Offset(0, 4).Value
            cell.Offset(0, 7) = "Updated"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cellx
Next cell
```

The Goal is to convert this to a usable array to work my comparisons in memory instead of directly on the worksheet.

I do not fully understand how the multi-dimensional Array works and I am having a hard time with setting up the function.

How would I go about loading the data into a multi-dimensional Array? I think I can do the comparisons myself but I am not sure how to load it into an Array.

I am thinking I will need to load all the columns that will need data and load all the columns from the look up spreadsheet then return all values found to each row. The problem is I am not sure how to apply the values to the columns within the row in the array.

Say I have sheet 1 that looks like this:

```
Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3 | Header 4 | Header 5
333      |          |          |          |
222      |          |          |          |
111      |          |          |          |
444      |          |          |          |
```

I have this other spreadsheet with all the updated data I am looking for.

```
Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3 | Header 4
111      | 1/2/2018 | AAA      | Active
222      | 1/4/2018 | BBB      | Active
333      | 1/1/2018 | CCC      | NA
444      | 1/12/2018| DDD      | NA
```

I Need to check header 1 against the same header 1 in the 2nd sheet and then return all values of that row back to the first sheet. And for the last header in sheet 2 (header 4) to be moved to header 5 in the 1st sheet.

Should return something like this on sheet 1:

```
Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3 | Header 4 | Header 5
333      | 1/1/2018 | CCC      |          | NA
222      | 1/4/2018 | BBB      |          | Active
111      | 1/2/2018 | AAA      |          | Active
444      | 1/12/2018| DDD      |          | NA
```

I can do this already with a few for loops comparing values on the spreadsheet but this is wayyyy slow. 22 Min is too long. I know how to compare 2 normal Arrays but not how to do this with 2D Arrays.

Comment: If vlookup can be adapted to output to multiple cells, it seems like that should work here

Comment: Do you need a macro? Unless I'm missing something, I think you could use `VLOOKUP()` or `INDEX/MATCH` formulas instead.

Comment: @BruceWayne I do need a macro. This is only a small part of a much larger macro. This is the last step and it takes up 22 min of the 24 total time when processing this sheet. The work is done between 6 spreadsheets. Vlookup could work but I am trying to avoid in sheet formulas.

Answer (score 0):

I would still like to understand how to work this data in a 2D Array as I am sure I will need them in the future however I did manage to create some Vlookup's *(As [Marcucciboy2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2727437/marcucciboy2) and [BruceWayne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4650297/brucewayne) pointed out)* that speed up the processing time to roughly 30 sec.

This is the code I managed to come up with to improve my processing time from 22 min to 30 sec if anyone is interested:

```
With inv_wb.Worksheets(6)
    lr_counter = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = .Range("A2:A" & lr_counter)
    lr_counter = vl_ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng2 = vl_ws.Range("A2:E" & lr_counter)

    For Each cell In rng1
        cellx = cell.Value
        If Not Application.IfError(Application.VLookup(cellx, rng2, 1, False), "none") = "none" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1) = UCase(Application.VLookup(cellx, rng2, 2, False))
            cell.Offset(0, 2) = Application.Text(Application.VLookup(cellx, rng2, 3, False), "MM/DD/YYYY")
            cell.Offset(0, 3) = Application.VLookup(cellx, rng2, 4, False)
            cell.Offset(0, 6) = Application.VLookup(cellx, rng2, 5, False)
            cell.Offset(0, 7) = "Updated"
        Else
            cell.Offset(0, 7) = "No Update"
        End If
    Next cell
End With
```